# Canasta: Can I open with a dirty Canasta without a natural and without points

Tags: canasta

Can I open with a canasta, JJJJJ22, without a  natural and without minimum card points?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

From [the rules](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#american-initial):

> The first meld made by each team during a hand is subject to some conditions. There are three possible ways to make a valid initial meld.
>
> > 2. The Splash
> >    If you have a natural canasta (seven natural cards of the same rank) or a wild card canasta (seven cards that are twos or jokers) in your hand, you may meld them as the initial meld for your team. In this case you do not have to meet any minimum count requirement.

Note that I am assuming this question is about Modern American Canasta, as such a meld would always be illegal in Classic Canasta (you cannot have a meld of only wild cards).